# Why does Ya'aqov refer to Paddan-Aram simply as Paddan?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avot-patriarch-fathers, geography, vayechi

If I'm not mistaken, Paddan-Aram is only ever referred to by its full name (i.e. Paddan-Aram). Nevertheless, Ya'aqov Avinu at the end of his life, refers to it simply as Paddan ([Bereshit 48:7](http://chabad.org/8243#v=7&showrashi=true)):

> וַאֲנִי | בְּבֹאִי מִפַּדָּן מֵתָה עָלַי רָחֵל בְּאֶרֶץ כְּנַעַן בַּדֶּרֶךְ בְּעוֹד כִּבְרַת אֶרֶץ לָבֹא אֶפְרָתָה וָאֶקְבְּרֶהָ שָּׁם בְּדֶרֶךְ אֶפְרָת הִוא בֵּית לָחֶם
>
> As for me, when I came from Padan, Rachel died to me in the land of Canaan on the way, when there was still a stretch of land to come to Ephrath, and I buried her there on the way to Ephrath, which is Bethlehem.

Why the omission of the suffix "Aram"?

Comment: Is there any other place where someone says the term, not just the "narrator"?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yitzchak did, when he told Ya'akov to leave home. "[קוּם לֵךְ פַּדֶּנָה אֲרָם בֵּיתָה בְתוּאֵל אֲבִי אִמֶּךָ](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)"

Comment: @waf Nice, though perhaps Padena Aram instead of Padan-Aramah may actually support a disconnect between the words.

Comment: Padan Aram is not one place; Aram is a known region, Padan is a place within that region where Nachor's family lived; Padan Aram is essentially the equivalent of Padan, Aram - much like New York, New York or Jerusalem, Israel.

Comment: @DovF Very nice, thanks. Any reason why this formulation appears only here?